# cron and lftp issue

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

I have the following scripts running on raspbian.

start

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/config/commands 2>&1 > /root/log/$HOSTNAME.log
```

commands

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/config/variables
echo TestLine
/usr/bin/lftp ftp://user:pass@host.com -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no ; set net:reconnect-interval-base 5 ; set net:max-retries 2 ; mirror -e /testgroup/music /root/media ; quit"
/usr/bin/mail -s "$HOSTNAME Report" $emailaddress < $logdir/$HOSTNAME.log``
```

When I run "start" manually I receive the email below

```
TestLine
Total: 1 directory, 4 files, 0 symlinks
```

When I run it using cron, I get the following email

`TestLine`

This is how crontab -e is set up

`@daily /root/start`

Any idea why would cron strip the lftp output from the email?

Comment: I bet the object of your email is "some-hostname Report" when run interractively and " Report" when run with Cron, Amirite?

Comment: What appears in /root/log/$HOSTNAME.log?

Comment: Exactly what you see in the original post. Whatever is in $HOSTNAME.log is emailed to me

Answer (score 1):

cron does not run with the same environnent as 
an interactive shell. Your `$HOSTNAME` variable is not set.

You can set it at the start of your script like so:

```
HOSTNAME="`/usr/bin/hostname`"
```

Comment: Actually the subject works. I get the operating system host name  in the subject.

I've also added HOSTNAME="`/bin/hostname`" in the "start" script (thats the path of hostname binary) and I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time fighting against the problem myself. Decided to go with `screen`. E.g.

```
screen -dmS screen_name bash -c '/root/start'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. lftp simply does not output that line when run from cron, but it still does its job.